# db2 select query with between and partition

Tags: sql, db2, between, partition

Please i need some help with this query

```
SELECT UNIDADE, MATRICULA, NOME, CURSO, ESCOLA, DTATU, HRATU, STATUS,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NOME ) AS CONT FROM (

SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATRICULA ORDER BY DTATU DESC,HRATU DESC) AS RN,
row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY NOME ) AS rid, UNIDADE, MATRICULA, NOME, CURSO, ESCOLA, DTATU, HRATU, STATUS FROM MOV_PROTOCOLO WHERE MATRICULA!='' ) AS t WHERE MATRICULA!=''and RN = 1) as V WHERE V.CONT BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

I want to select this query between 0 and 10 rows!

Something like that

```
PLACE CODE STATUS CONT

001 41309014 OK 1
001 31121810 OK 2
001 41309634 OK 3
001 31414303 OK 4
001 41461487 OK 5
001 41207203 OK 6
001 41444868 OK 7
001 31344046 OK 8
001 41447131 OK 9
001 41083326 OK 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean something like that

```
SELECT UNIDADE, MATRICULA, NOME, CURSO, ESCOLA, DTATU, HRATU, STATUS
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NOME) AS rid
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATRICULA ORDER BY DTATU DESC,HRATU DESC) AS RN,
            UNIDADE, MATRICULA, NOME, CURSO, ESCOLA, DTATU, HRATU, STATUS
        FROM MOV_PROTOCOLO
        WHERE MATRICULA!=''
    ) AS t
    WHERE t.RN = 1
) as V
WHERE V.rid BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```